# Entered the liscene key and Toad shows an error.Error message says" TOAD encountered a serious error and must be closed

Tags: database, toad

Toad Data Point 3.4.0.2038
System.Collections. Generic.keynotfoundexception:
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Stacktrace:
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'1.get.Item(Tkey key)

Comment: is that a legitimate license?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question for StackOverflow. I'd go to Dell's support and get assistance since you can't even license your product.